# "So ist er gut"

Tags: grammar-identification

I was reading an article about a football manager talking at the end of a match:

> "So ist Fußball. So ist er gut. So ist er toll."

I know that *so* is a complicated word in German, but for the sentence

> So ist Fußball

I thought *so* meant "That"

but in

> So ist er gut

I thought it meant "That is good."

But what is the purpose of **er** in that sentence.

What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this sentence, »so« means »in this manner« / »when done that way« / etc. You can read more about this meaning in https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa#Bedeutung1a, entry 1a. Thus one may render the sentences as

> That way is how football is. When done that way, it is good. When done that way, it is great.

A more idiomatic translation might be

> That's football. It's good like that. It's great like that.

So the »er« is a personal pronoun, masculine, which refers to football (»Fußball«).

Comment: Yep so the "so" actually has two functions in that sentence - "That is" and "In that way"

Comment: IOW, loosely translated: "That's football. That's the way I like it. That's the way I love it!".

Comment: The first translation is bad, the second one is **much** better

Comment: @PiedPiper I agree. The first translation was meant to be more or less literal, so that the meaning of »so« becomes clear.

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear to the OP and any other learner that this is not what they should be emulating

Comment: Strictly speaking, "so" does not mean "that". It just happens that you can translate "so" in the first sentence by "that". But its meaning is "like this" in alle three sentences. So a more literal translation is "Football is like this. If it's like this, it's good. If it's like this, it's great."